# SQL Server 2012 Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. The one is `products` and the other is `suppliers`. The table `products` has `product_id`, `product_price`, `product_name`, `supplier_id` and `category_id` columns. The `supplier_id` is the foreign key from `suppliers` table and the `product_id` is the primary key. The `suppliers` table has `supplier_id`, `supplier_name`, `state` and `city` columns. The query that I want to make is "select full details of the supplier with the largest number of products." I was thinking  something like this:

`SELECT * FROM suppliers INNER JOIN products ON suppliers.supplier_id=products.supplier_id;`

but I dont know how to count every supplier's products. 
Any ideas?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: take a look at `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't join. You want data *from* the suppliers table *where* a certain condition (largest number of products) is given. Hence `suppliers` in the `FROM` clause, `products` in the `WHERE` clause.

You'd group the `products` table by `supplier_id`, so as to get an aggregate per supplier. Order by count and take the top record(s).

```
select * 
from suppliers
where supplier_id in
(
  select top(1) with ties
    supplier_id
  from products
  group by supplier_id
  order by count(*) desc
);
```